# por qué no funciona el siguiente código para modificar las cabeceras (headers) de una respuesta http?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, headers, middleware

Esta pregunta trata sobre cabeceras en una respuesta HTTP. He conseguido resolver el problema, pero no entiendo por qué inicialmente no funcionaba.

Se trata de un servidor que emite respuestas HTTP para *API calls*, según la cabecera del *request* queremos que se incluyan una serie de cabeceras en la respuesta. Por ejemplo: todas las peticiones de deben tener un *token* en la cabecera, salvo la de *login*, de no tenerlo se envía una respuesta de error.

Esto es lo que inicialmente programé que no funciona:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();// mas codigo para meter healthchecks endpoints

            });

            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Service");
                c.RoutePrefix = "swagger";
            });

            app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleware) =>
            {
                context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
                {
                    
                    
                    //if there is not a valid token and it is not a login request
                    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("x-session-token"))
                    {
                        var token = context.Request.Headers["x-session-token"].ToString();
                        var time = DateTime.Now;
                        if (!tokenDetails.ContainsKey(token)) { context.Response.StatusCode = 404; }
                        else
                        {
                            var expireDate = tokenDetails[token];
                            if (expireDate < time)
                            {
                                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                            }
                        }
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    if (context.Request.QueryString.ToString().ToLower().Contains("login"))
                    {
                        // if it is from a login request
                        var token = getToken();
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-headers", "authorization, content-type, x-session-token");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-origin", "*");
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("x-session-token: ", "token" + token);
                        context.Response.Headers.Add("access-control-allow-max-age", "0");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                });
                await nextMiddleware();
            });
        }
```

Se usa MVC y .NET Core 3.1.

Mi principal problema es que cuando *testeaba* el servidor usando una aplicación que me he programado yo (no postman) observaba que las cabeceras no se enviaban. Al hacer un *debugging*, observaba que no se llegaba a este *middleware* para introducir la cabecera, pensé que el problema podía ser la situación de este *middleware* dentro del método `Configure`, así que lo fuí cambiando de situación y en todas *swagger* cascaba. ¿Alguién me puede explicar por qué las cabeceras no se añadían?.

Como solución, ahora lo hago desde el controlador añadiendo `Response.Headers.Add("cabecera", "valor");`, pero no entiendo por qué haciéndolo desde `Configure` no funciona, no se llega a esa parte de código, ¿alguien me lo puede explicar?

Para solucionar el problema he ido controlador por controlador creando casos nuevos y mediante Response.Header.Add(cabecera, valor); o enviando respuestas de error, no entiendo por qué el configure no tiraba

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intenta colocar el `app.Use` de primero antes de los demás `Use...`

[image: Ejemplo de codigo para incluir cabecera a todas las llamadas http]

[image: Ejemplo de la cabecera agregada]

En esta documentación se explica: [Middleware order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order)

Comment: Bien, Heli! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Para las personas que no leen inglés, puedes expandir un poco tu solución? Sería mucho más educativo para los usuarios obtener una explicación de por qué ocurre el fenómeno reportado, y luego un link a la documentación oficial para saber más.

Comment: En realidad es necesario publicar el código dentro de una imagen? Sugiero que el código se publique como texto.

Comment: no me funciona, el swagger peta

Comment: gracias habia otro error amayores